# Should one load the dataset before or inside of the function?

Tags: r, function, dataset, package

**Q.** How does one write an R package **function** that references an R package **dataset** in a way that is **simple/friendly/efficient** for an R user. For example, how does one handle `afunction()` that calls `adataset` from a package?

**What I think may not be simple/friendly/efficient:**
User is required to run
`data(adataset)` before running 
`afunction(...)`
or else receiving an `Error: ... object 'adataset' not found`. I have noticed some packages have built-in datasets that can be called anytime the package is loaded, for example, `iris`, which one can call without bringing it to the Global Environment.

Possible options which I have entertained:

1. **Write `data(NamedDataSet)` directly into the function.**  Is this a bad idea. I thought perhaps it could be, looking at memory and given my limiting understanding of function environments.
2. **Code the structure of the dataset directly into the function.** I think this works depending on the size of the data but it makes me wonder about how to go about proper documentation in the package.
3. **Change Nothing.** Given a large enough dataset, maybe it does not make sense to implement a way different from reading it before calling the function.

Any comments are appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might find these resources about writing R data packages useful:

- [the "External Data" section of R Packages](http://r-pkgs.had.co.nz/data.html)
- [Creating an R data package](http://thecoatlessprofessor.com/programming/creating-an-r-data-package/)
- [Creating an R data package (overview)](http://www.clayford.net/statistics/creating-an-r-data-package/)

In particular, take note of the `DESCRIPTION` file and usage of the line `LazyData: true`. This is how datasets are made available without having to use `data()`, as in the `iris` example that you mention.

Comment: The "Internal data" section of the first link most likely gives the answer. Save the data in `R/sysdata.rda` (or use `devtools::use_data(..., internal = TRUE)` to have devtools do this for you).